# Wiimotes reinstall drivers every time they connect

Tags: windows-7, drivers, dolphin-emulator, wiimote

Can some one help me to skip the installation of the drivers? Every time I want to connect the Wiimotes to my PC (running Windows 7) it has to install the drivers for each of them every time.

Comment: Do you know what type of Wiimote you're using? Some newer Wiimotes can have connection issues with Windows 7. ([See Dolphin's Wiimote Plus Connection Guide](https://dolphin-emu.org/docs/guides/wii-remote-plus-rvl-cnt-01-tr-connection-guide/))